# Import @Configuration class from one project to another

Tags: java, spring

I have to projects: ProjectA and ProjectB.

In ProjectA I have:

```
    package somePackageOfProjectA;
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "bla.bla" })
    public class ProjectAConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 
    ..
    }
```

In the classpath of ProjectB I've added ProjectA and I have the next configuration:

```
    package somePackageOfProjectB;
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Import(ProjectAConfig .class)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "bla.bla" })
    public class ProjectBConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 
    ..
    }
```

Until now all good, without any compilation error (ProjectAConfig  is recognized in ProjectB).

The problem appear when I start the server. For an unknown reason is trying to search somePackageOfProjectA.ProjectAConfig only in ProjectB without searching it in  ProjectA and an error occurs because is not existing.

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of trying to import that configuration, i would recommend to extend ProjectA from ProjectB, have you tried that?
And if you want to import, then make sure that ComponentScan is looking for packages where ProjectA is located

Comment: I've added ComponentScan but I have same problem. How should I extend ProjectA from ProjectB by using Maven?

Comment: in maven for ProjectB you can say that parent project is ProjectA

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure, but it feels wrong to me to have two classes that extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter inside the same web application, what did you expect Spring to do, merge the list of ViewResolvers and HttpMessageConverters?

If you have beans that you want to reuse between projects, I would suggest that you put them into a separate @Configuration class instead og the class that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.

Comment: I removed extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter from ProjectAConfig  and I got another problem. It seems that ProjectAConfig  is not visible to ProjectB because I get j"ava.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy" exception.